# How to integrate tapandpay android

Tags: android, google-pay, android-pay, wallet, android-tap-and-pay

I am making an android library where i want to access the tapandpay methods i.e. getActiveWalletId and getTokenStatus etc.
I have tried adding the following dependency but am still unable to resolve tapandpay.
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tapandpay:17.1.0'

I need to figure out exactly how the google pay whitelisting works, is it based on the signing fingerprint? App ID? As i am working on a library.

Is it possible to have an SDK that is capable of adding cards to wallet etc.
I cant find much on the internet regarding tapandpay because it has private access.
Can you help me find the documentation of tapandpay or guide me through the process to get my app whitelisted for wallet apps and how to access the tapandpay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request access to the sdk using this form: https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/request-access

Google usually dispatch the request in 1 day.

In that form you usually don't need to specify your app fingerprint, only the package name is enough.

Also keep in mind that this sdk doesn't work on emulator.

Since the whitelist is done on your production app fingerprint, don't forget to use the production signing keys even for the debug build, otherwise you will get15009 error.